# What does LW stand for in liblwgeom of PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, terminology

What does `LW` stand for in `liblwgeom` of PostGIS?

I could not find any explanation anywhere, or in the source code (mirrored) at https://github.com/postgis/postgis/tree/svn-trunk/liblwgeom

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The LW in LWGEOM stands for "light-weight."

Here's a reference from the archives:
https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/2.4.4/NEWS#L2045

Comment: I wonder if it is documented somewhere. The packagers seem to know the origin of the name somehow https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libs/liblwgeom-2.1.4.